# MI6 SPEC OPS: What difficulty rating should I use to get 4 stars?

Tags: ps3, goldeneye-007

Playing on the PS3 version of ***Goldeneye 007 Reloaded***.

Just completed my first MI6 OPS mission (station - stealth) and I used default modifiers and got myself two stars for the effort. Bearing in mind I did it in about 3.5 mins, what do I need to do to get 4 stars?

I know making it more difficult will probably do the trick, but what "Difficulty Rating" do I want to aim for to make 4 stars achievable?

**EDIT**: On the same mission (station) I upped all the mods except "Enemy Health" (so I could still get head shot kills) and this gave me a difficulty rating of 2448 - I did this in 3 mins 27 secs and still only got 2 stars, my final score was around 35000.

Are there any factors other than speed that contribute to a high score? Such as killing with subdue, accuracy etc.

Comment: which game is this? The Wii version or the N64?

Comment: PS3, I thought I had tagged this. And there is no SPEC OPS on the N64 version